# Script keeps showing array to string conversion mistake

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I created an array and stored it inside a $_SESSION variable, now I want to include that array inside a MySQL select statement to get more infos depending on p, which is included in my URL. My code is included inside a HTML page, which is completely empty except for necessary HTML and of course session_start, so this is not the problem. The code looks like that:

```
<?php
$p = $_GET["p"];

var_dump($_SESSION['questions'][$p]);

include("../script/db_connect.php");

$p = $_GET["p"];

$select_right_question = "select * from questions where id = '{$_SESSION['questions'][$p]}'";

$question_infos = mysqli_query($con, $select_right_question);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($question_infos)) {
    echo $row["question"] . '</br>'
        . $row["right_answer"] . '</br>'
        . $row["answer2"] . '</br>'
        . $row["answer3"] . '</br>'
        . $row["answer4"];
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I already tested it and the main issue is the following line:

```
$select_right_question = "select * from questions where id = '{$_SESSION['questions'][$p]}'";
```

What is the correct way to include the SESSION variable here?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). I'd also suggest you dump both `$p` and `$_SESSION['questions'][$p]` to see what they contain. It sounds like either $p or $_SESSION['questions'][$p] is an array instead of a string.

Comment: What is the output from the `var_dump`?

Comment: @aynber where coulde SQL injection happen? All my infos from $row are stored inside a database, before storing I used mysqli_real_escape_string on them.

As I said, $_SESSION['questions'][$p] is an array

Comment: @RossWilson var_dump says array(1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "74" }

Comment: `$_SESSION['questions'][$p]['id']`

Comment: Thanks mate! That was quick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the security issues with your code, and assuming `$_SESSION['questions'][$p]` is returning an array, you can modify your SQL statement to:

```
$select_right_question = "select * from questions where id = '{$_SESSION['questions'][$p]['id']}'";
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! What should I change to avoid these security issues?

Comment: As @aynber mentioned, you should switch to Prepared Statements. All input should be sanitised too. There are other things you can do too, so consider reading up on it.